# Read multiple files from directory with Node.js using Promises/Async/Await

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise, node.js-fs

I'm trying to scan a local directory for all of the text files within it, then read each of those files. I want to do it properly using promises, async, and await, but something is going wrong and am stuck trying to figure it out.

I am able to read the directory contents and output all of the filenames correctly, but when I try to read those files themselves using the `map` method, I get a `Promise { <pending> }` log for each of the files. Also, I get a `UnhandledPromiseRejection` error at the end.

I can read a single file fine outside of the `map` function, but can't loop through all of the files and read them without getting an error.

```
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

const textFileDir = `${__dirname}/files/`;

const readDirPro = (dir) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readdir(dir, (error, files) => {
      if (error) reject('Could not find directory');
      resolve(files);
    });
  });
};

const readFilePro = (file) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(file, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
      if (err) reject('Could not find file');
      resolve(data);
    });
  });
};

const readAllFiles = async () => {
  try {
    const dirFilesArr = await readDirPro(textFileDir);
    // correctly outputs array of file names in directory
    // console.log('dirFilesArr: ', dirFilesArr);

    // THIS IS THE PROBLEM:
    await dirFilesArr.map((file) => {
      // console.log(file);
      // correctly outputs filenames
      const fileContent = readFilePro(file);
      // console.log(fileContent);
      // incorrectly outputs "Promise { <pending> }" logs for each file
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`catch (err): ${err}`);

    throw err;
  }
  return '2: final return';
};

(async () => {
  try {
    console.log('1: readAllFiles!');
    const x = await readAllFiles();
    console.log(x);
    console.log('3: Done!');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`IIFE catch ERROR : ${err}`);
  }
})();
```

Here's is the full console output for that javascript, with the `Promise {  } logs commented out:

```
1: readAllFiles!
2: final return
3: Done!
node:internal/process/promises:289
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "Could not find file".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}

Node.js v19.0.1
```

I would prefer to keep the working solution as close to this code as possible, because it's is actually one piece of a larger puzzle, and I need to be able to continue utilizing this structure.

My ultimate goal is to read all of those files, pull certain data from them, then write that data into a new JSON file.

---

**UPDATE:** Check this answer below for the most exact solution to the question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75206022/3787666

Comment: `readFilePro()` returns a pending promise.  That's what it does.  The caller has to use `await` or `.then()` on that promise to know when it's done and get the result.

Comment: Do you realize that promise versions already exist for the `fs` module?  See [fsPromises.readFile()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromisesreadfilepath-options) in the doc.

Comment: thanks, @jfriend00, but where does that await go?  I have one before the map method here, and if I try it like this `const fileContent = await readFilePro(file);`, then I get an "Unexpected reserved word" error

Comment: As for fsPromises.readFile(), are you saying I could use that instead of the readFilePro function here?

Comment: Yes, it's built into the `fs` module.  You don't have to make your own promisified versions.

Comment: I'm still not clear on how that helps with my issue here.  I need to be able to loop through all of the files and read them.  I have to be able to read the directory then dynamically read each file in that directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251315/discussion-between-david-and-jfriend00).

Comment: Maybe this link can help you : https://medium.com/@leonardobrunolima/javascript-tips-asynchronous-iteration-7a13649a3348

Comment: Thanks, @phili_b.  Definitely in the right ball park, figuring out how to await promises with a map method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NodeJS has promisified version of `fs`, so technically you can achieve the desired results with the following code:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

const textFileDir = `${__dirname}/files/`;

(async () => {
  try {
    console.log('1: readAllFiles!');
    const dirFilesArr = await fs.promises.readdir(textFileDir);
    const files = await Promise.all(dirFilesArr.map((file) => {
        const fullPath = path.join(textFileDir, file);
        return fs.promises.readFile(fullPath, { encoding: 'utf-8' });
    }));
    console.log(files);
    console.log('3: Done!');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`IIFE catch ERROR : ${err}`);
  }
})();
```

If you prefer to fix your original code, you will need to make a few changes.
First change is needed because `readdir` doesn't return file names with full pathes and as a result, you need to add a path to each file to read a file.
Therefore, your `readFilePro` should look something like so:

```
const readFilePro = (file) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(path.join(textFileDir, file), 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
      if (err) reject('Could not find file');
      resolve(data);
    });
  });
};
```

The second change is that your `readAllFiles` needs to be changed like so:

```
const readAllFiles = async () => {
  try {
    const dirFilesArr = await readDirPro(textFileDir);
    return Promise.all(dirFilesArr.map((file) => readFilePro(file)));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`catch (err): ${err}`);

    throw err;
  }
  return '2: final return';
};
```

In your original code, you run `readFilePro` for each file and retrieve a promise that you never wait. The approach above fixes the problem.

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Providing two solutions even.  I was just looking at handling the `map` method with a `Promise.all` and that turns out to be a key part of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the accepted answer above, here's a supplemental answer, which addresses a key aspect of my question.  Rather than returning all of the data in in one big chunk from the `map`, I really needed to be able to manipulate data from each file as soon as it is read (why I had the `const fileContent` in my question above).  So, this is how I handle that now, by using an `async/await` for the callback ***inside*** of the `map` method.  I still need the `Promise.all` method with the `return` if I want to pass `const files` data to a function following the `Promise.all`.

```
const files = await Promise.all(
      dirFilesArr.map(async (file, i) => {
        const fullPath = path.join(textFileDir, file);
        const fileContent = await fs.promises.readFile(fullPath, {
          encoding: 'utf-8',
        });
        //console.log(fileContent); // can now view file data individually
        await externalFunction(fileContent, i); // manipulating file data
        // return fs.promises.readFile(fullPath, { encoding: 'utf-8' });
      })
    );
```

Comment: @RAllen  Your super helpful answer got me to this point.  Thanks again